# What is the purpose of IntentSender?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to known what is the purpose of the [`IntentSender`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.html) class for our application? How do we use it in our application?

Are there any good examples, apart from [The Android Intent Based APIs: Part Seven – IntentSenders And PendingIntents](http://justanapplication.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/the-android-intent-based-apis-part-seven-intentsenders-and-pendingintents/)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`IntentSender`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.html) is kind of a level of abstraction or glue class that allows you to

1. Receive broadcast when user selects application in chooser.

   Example when you use `IntentSender`:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
       .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.")
       .setType("text/plain");
   Intent receiver = new Intent(this, BroadcastTest.class)
       .putExtra("test", "test");
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "test", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
   startActivity(chooser);
   ```
2. Start `Activity` with `IntentSender` instead of `Intent` (more in [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startIntentSender(android.content.IntentSender,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)))

   > `startIntentSender(IntentSender intent, Intent fillInIntent, int flagsMask, int flagsValues, int extraFlags, Bundle options)`
   >
   > Like `startActivity(Intent, Bundle)`, but taking a `IntentSender` to start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nice to notice that the developer can use `(ComponentName) intent.getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT)` in its receiver `onReceive()` method to get the chosen application info (package name, etc ...).

Answer (score 6):

The official Android developer documentation for [`IntentSender`](https://github.com/vogellacompany/codeexamples-android/blob/master/de.vogella.android.apitest/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmController.java#L92) clearly states:

> Instances of this class can not be made directly, but rather must be created from an existing `PendingIntent` with `PendingIntent.getIntentSender()`.

So, you would(should) not see this class being used directly in a code sample or tutorial.

As for a `PendingIntent`, it's basically a token that you give to another application which allows that application to use your app's permissions to execute a specific piece of your app's code.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/codeexamples-android/blob/master/de.vogella.android.apitest/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmController.java#L92) of a `PendingIntent` used in a class.