# Not receiving broadcast form IntentSender

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to get a broadcast when the user select in a chooser as stated [What is the purpose of IntentSender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583230/what-is-the-purpose-of-intentsender#answer-34314156) and [Get IntentSender object for createChooser method in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631902/get-intentsender-object-for-createchooser-method-in-android).

I create the chooser as describer in both post:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.")
    .setType("text/plain");
Intent receiver = new Intent(this, BroadcastTest.class)
    .putExtra("test", "test");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "test", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
startActivity(chooser);
```

and register my BroadcastReceiver in my AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.migore.intentsender.BroadcastTest"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
        <action android:name="com.migore.intentsender.intent.TEST" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

However, my receiver is never called. I already tried registering the receiver in the code but it also didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing the intent-filter from the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Hello use bellow code

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.migore.intentsender.BroadcastTest"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
            <action droid:name="android.intent.extra.CHOSEN_COMPONENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```