# How to handle createChooser's IntentSender without having the component class of the receiver Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-intent-chooser

I am trying to handle the `IntentSender` of `Intent.createChooser()` to do something when a user selects an app to share an image on. Most the examples I've found here (posted below), require using a `BroadcastReceiver` [as follows](https://medium.com/code-with-lisa/get-results-from-android-chooser-9cfc5445a871):

```
Intent receiver = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
String type = "image/*";
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType(type);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, awesome_photo_uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "some_title", pendingIntent.getIntentSender()));
```

My problem with this solution, is located in this line:

```
Intent receiver = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
```

The [Intent constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)) used in these examples require me to make a static `MyReceiver` class, so I have a class to pass into the second argument of the constructor. But, this causes an issue because **I'd like the `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` to do stuff in my Fragment.** Therefore, I would prefer to create a `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically in my Fragment.

To no avail, I attempted the following work-around:

Inside `MyFragment.kt`:

```
private val receiver: BroadcastReceiver = getBroadcastReceiver()
private val intentFilter = IntentFilter("com.my.app.CHOOSER_ACTION")

override fun onResume() {
    requireContext().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)
    super.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    requireContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    super.onPause()
}

private fun shareImage(imageFile: File) {
    Intent().apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        type = "image/*"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            requireContext(),
            "${myPackageName}.fileprovider",
            imageFile
        ))

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            val receiver = Intent("com.my.app.CHOOSER_ACTION")
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireContext(), 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(this, "Share image using", pendingIntent.intentSender))
        } else {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(this, "Share image using"))
        }
    }
}

private fun getBroadcastReceiver() : BroadcastReceiver {
    return object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            intent?.extras?.keySet()?.forEach {
                Log.v("MyTest", "$it: ${intent.extras?.get(it)}")
            }
            doSomethingInMyFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivityThatHasMyFragment" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.my.app.CHOOSER_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Unfortunately, the dynamic `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()` function is never called after the user presses on a selection. A few questions:

1. Why does this not work? What am I missing? Am I somehow setting the `Intent` or `IntentFilter` incorrectly?
2. Is it even possible to use a dynamic `BroadcastReceiver` for handling the `IntentSender` of `createChooser`? If not, how can I create a static `BroadcastReceiver` that triggers something to happen in `MyFragment`?

**Resources:**

- [Get IntentSender object for createChooser method in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631902/get-intentsender-object-for-createchooser-method-in-android)
- [Get results from Android Chooser](https://medium.com/code-with-lisa/get-results-from-android-chooser-9cfc5445a871)
- [How to tell which app was selected by Intent.createChooser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203230/how-to-tell-which-app-was-selected-by-intent-createchooser)
- [What is the purpose of IntentSender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583230/what-is-the-purpose-of-intentsender)
- [Intent.createChooser()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender))

Comment: On Android 8.0+, implicit broadcasts like yours are banned -- try also calling `setPackage()` on the `Intent` to see if you can get past this, or switch to `createPendingResult()` on your `Activity` (which gives you a `PendingIntent` that triggers `onActivityResult()` on the same activity). You might also see if there are interesting messages in Logcat at the point you interact with the chooser. BTW, the `<intent-filter>` element does not belong on the activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for the createPendingResult() idea. In my fragment, I put `val pendingIntent = requireActivity().createPendingResult(1234, Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)` and I'm excited to see that I'm getting the result from my activity's `onActivityResult`. Is there there a way to get it to work with Fragments? In other words, my fragment's `onActivityResult` would handle it instead. Or will I just have to manually call my fragment's `onActivityResult` from my Activity?

Comment: "Or will I just have to manually call my fragment's onActivityResult from my Activity?" -- yes, sorry.